# In UML, can a component be placed inside a node?

Tags: uml, diagrams, language-specifications

in UML deployment diagrams, the *node* element is used to represent a "computational resource" (in other words, something that can run software).

I know that nodes may have other nodes placed inside them (to imply nesting), and that they may have *artifacts* placed inside them (to imply the deployment relationship, i. e. the artifact being deployed to the node).

However, I've also found a couple of illustrations that had *component* elements placed inside a node, which I'm not sure how to interpret.

Here's what I'd like to know:

- Is it legal to place a component inside a node?
- If so, what exactly does it imply - the component being deployed to the node (which I'm not sure is allowed), or the node consisting of the component?
- If not, does the specification explicitly say so at any point?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_diagram#/media/File:Deployment_Diagram.PNG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, no, it is not legal to place a component inside a node.
The specification does not explicitly say so, but it would not be feasible for the spec to explicitly forbid every mistake one could possibly make.

Personally, I think it is acceptable to draw a component inside a node. I would interpret it as a deployed artifact implementing that component.

Some relevant quotes from the UML 2.5 specification:

> 11.6.3.1: A Component may be manifested by one or more Artifacts, and in turn, that Artifact may be deployed to its execution environment.
>
> 19.4.3: A Node is computational resource upon which Artifacts may be deployed. Nodes may be further sub-typed as Devices and ExecutionEnvironments.
>
> 19.2.4: System elements deployed on a DeployedTarget, and Deployments that connect them, may be drawn inside the perspective cube.

I think DeployedTarget is a typo or a synonym for DeploymentTarget, which is a superclass of Node. "System elements" is not well defined in the spec. I found this sentence:

> 19.2.3: System elements are represented as DeployedTargets

But I think this should not be treated as a formal definition of the word 'system element' as used in 19.2.4. I think it is clear that anything drawn inside a node should be something deployed on that node and the only deployments mentioned are the deployments of artifacts.